# Can we modify any hash function like SHA-1 or MD5 to perform multiple iterations at once to gain calculation speed?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design

Is it mathematically possible to adapt a given hash function (f.e. SHA-1 or MD5) so it performs a known number of iterations at once?

Concrete example would be:

```
data = SHA1_10000(data)
```

instead of:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) data = SHA1(data)
```

while resulting in the same output, but being 10000 times faster.

Comment: What you ask is not possible via modification to hash. However, you could be interested in [Merkle tree (also known as hash tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), which is a way to use hash that (in some settings) allows gaining speed by enabling (amongst other things) parallel computation of blocks of input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would find something like this, it would probably even point to a weakness in the hash function.

**Impossiblity in the random oracle model.** Hash functions are often assumed to behave like random oracles (i.e., for every new query they return a uniformly random value, while answering consistently for repeated queries). For a random oracle, the output is not defined before querying the random oracle at the input - so in this model it should be relatively easy to argue that it is impossible to find what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

In many instances, although we want computing a hash to be polynomial in time, we do not want it to be too fast since this will make it easier for an attacker to brute force finding a pre-image. Hashes are therefore constructed in a way to make the computation as serial as possible to slow them down, even using very parallel architectures like GPUs.

Comment: Indeed. We can't make the total computation require much less work than 10000 hashes (as stated in the [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55062/555)). And also, we can't make it much faster than 10000 times the duration of a single hash, no matter how much hardware we throw at it.